# JRebel rebel.xml configuration problems using web and link elements

Tags: java, configuration, jrebel

I have the following rebel.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="${project.dir}/src/main/resources"/>
        <!-- Useful for classes when IDE auto compile on save is enabled, classes will be redeployed -->
        <dir name="${project.dir}/target/classes"/>
        <dir name="${project.dir}/target/digital-entitlement/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    </classpath>

<!--     <web> -->
<!--         <link target="/"> -->
<!--             <dir name="${project.dir}/src/main/webapp"/> -->
<!--         </link> -->
<!--     </web> -->

</application>
```

with it class reloading is working fine.
But when I uncomment the `<web>` fragment above, to enable web assets reloading, then the web app hangs on a login form test case:

- w/o the `<web>` config the web page is loaded correctly and then submitting the un/pwd is ok triggering the reload of server side classes by jrebel when modified.
- Adding the `<web>` config hangs the browser and the initial login page is never loaded (selenium tests go in timeout after 30 secs).

**NOTE**: not all the web pages hang when the `<web>` config is enabled.

Thanks

Comment: What are the tests cases? The best thin to do: try enabling the logging with -Drebel.log=true, reproduce, and send the log file to their support.

Comment: Added test case in the question text and followed your suggestion sending email to their customer support.